# Solidify warps model

Tags: solidify-modifier

I have been trying to solidify this Ratchet that I've been resculpting from a Transformers Prime Wii Model. I still don't have Screenshots, but I do have the Blend File this time.

I've been struggling with solidifying this guy, and a lot of the solutions, applying scale, recalculating normals inside or outside, adjusting the settings of the Solidify modifier, cleaning up the model by removing duplicate faces and vertices, don't work. Some slightly fix the issue, but overall I can't get past .1 thickness in any setting without pieces warping, or the model solidifying in the opposite direction I want it to. I'm focusing on solidifying inward for a personal 3D Print.

This Blend file is a version of Ratchet right after I finished about 95% of the detailing I want, but right before fixing normals, cleaning up, or applying modifiers. I did try to apply as I went through, but all modifiers regularly failed to apply even though the changes still applied visually. I'm using this model so I could learn exactly what I screwed up, as I' fairly new to Blender in general.

Blender File:   [image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE! you have several issues. Duplicate overlapping vertices, inverted face normals, internal faces, and missing faces, [that all make your model non-manifold](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry) and not fit for 3d printing. Start by going through each part of the model and make them all manifold. https://snipboard.io/7Hnu3P.jpg There shouldnt be any red. everything must be blue.

Comment: Although there are only 179 duplicate vertices on your model, there are lots of overlapping triangular faces on it, many of which have face normals in the oposite direction to the face that they overlap so it's not surprising that a solidify modifier doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.